# Pine Script Execution on Historical Bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I had a read in the documentation on Pine and my understanding is that a script/strategy gets executed once per historical bar. I am trying to code in a stop loss to my strategy such that if I am in a trade and price falls below a previous bar low it should exit the trade. But if the script only triggers once per bar it wont capture price movements intrabar, how can I get around this?

my code is below:

```
// Define variables
var stopLoss = 0.0

// Initial account balance
var initBalance = 100000

// Calculate risk per trade as 1% of initial balance
var riskPerTrade = initBalance * 0.03

// Check if previous candle closed bullish
if barstate.isconfirmed[1] == true 
    if close[1] > open[1]
        // Set stop loss as previous candle low
        stopLoss = low[1]
        // Go long and set stop loss
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=stopLoss, qty=riskPerTrade/stopLoss)

// Exit trade if current candle closes or stop loss is hit
if barstate.isconfirmed[0] == true 
    strategy.close("Long")
else if low[0] <= stopLoss
    strategy.exit("Long")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, pinescript's scripts (strategies included of course) gets executed on specific occasions, most notably on bar close. That means that if you are checking inside your script if the `close` price is lower than a specific price, then it will return `true` or `false` only on bar close.

For example, this code will only get executed on bar close, regardless of the intra-bar prices:

```
if barstate.isconfirmed[0] == true 
    strategy.close("Long")
```

In addition to pinescript, TradingView offers a [broker emulator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#broker-emulator) for backtesting pinescript strategies, and from there you get the results you see of the backtesting. You can't really access the broker emulator directly, but I believe that most (if not all) the `strategy.*()` functions are sending and receiving information to and from that emulator.

Basically in the example given above, it's saying to the pinescript system: "when you run the script (usually on bar close) check for this condition. If it returns `true` send this `strategy.close()` order to the broker emulator and it'll close the position immediately".

As you mentioned, this will almost never result in an exact price, since it only check for the `close` price when bar is closed.

But pinescript has a way to send take profit and stop loss (and even trailing) orders to the broker emulator using [some parameters](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit) of the `strategy.exit()` function. Here are some examples:

> **limit (series int/float)** An optional parameter. Profit target (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a limit order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or better). Priority of the parameter 'limit' is higher than priority of the parameter 'profit' ('limit' is used instead of 'profit', if its value is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.

> **stop (series int/float)** An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or worse). Priority of the parameter 'stop' is higher than priority of the parameter 'loss' ('stop' is used instead of 'loss', if its value is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.

To use this, you can write something like (outside of an `if` statement) **:

```
strategy.exit('Long', stop= stopLoss)
```

This code will say to the pinescript system: "each time you run the code, send an exit order to the broker emulator stating that it should exit the position only if the "realtime" price (not the `close` price of the closed bar) is lower than `stopLoss` value, and keep this SL order until I say otherwise".

When this kind of order received by the broker emulator, he will continuously check the "realtime" price and will exit the position if minimum price is reached.

Keep in mind that there are some limitations to the broker emulator. For example, on backtesting, the broker emulator gets only 4 prices per bar - `open`, `high`, `low` and `close`, and it needs to decide when to exit the trade according to only those values. In order to do that, it makes some assumptions, which in some cases will not reflect the true result. For premium members there are some tools to overcome this, but that's another subject.

** In your code, `stopLoss` is set to `0` so it won't work. You can set the `stopLoss` to a price or number of ticks and change the parameters of the `strategy.exit()` function accordingly.